# Update another column based on IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have never used a IF query and just need some assistance please.

My query-:

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item AS a
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS b
ON a.item_id = b.entity_id
SET a.qty = $mssqlOnHand
WHERE b.sku = '$mssqlCode'
```

The above is updating the stock quantity using a value from our MS SQL database,what I would like to do is update another column. If the value was more than 0 to add the value 1, and 0 if it was 0 or below.

Would the below work?

```
IF '$mssqlCode' > 0
SET a.is_in_stock = 1
ELSE 
SET a.is_in_stock = 0
```

or would the order of the query allow me to use the qty directly-:

```
IF a.qty > 0
SET a.is_in_stock = 1
ELSE 
SET a.is_in_stock = 0
```

Some assistance would be great on how to setup this query.

Thankyou

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item AS a
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS b
ON a.item_id = b.entity_id
SET a.is= CASE WHEN a.qty>0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways you could do this..

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item AS a
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS b
ON a.item_id = b.entity_id
SET a.qty = $mssqlOnHand,
SET a.SomeOtherField = CASE WHEN $mssqlOnHand > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE b.sku = '$mssqlCode'
```

or you could use a calculated field and leave it out of the update statement. If it is one update, I would do the first, if it is every update, then do the second.

Hth,
Oli

EDIT: For the second option, define a column in the table like CalcColumn below..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
[SomeColumn] [int] NOT NULL,
[CalcColumn]  AS (case when [SomeColumn]>(0) then (1) else (0) end) PERSISTED NOT    NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Thank you so no IF at all! It is every update, can you explain how I would use a calculated field please?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
update a 
set a.is_in_stock = case when a.qty > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
from cataloginventory_stock_item AS a   
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS b 
ON a.item_id = b.entity_id
```

Hopefully it helps you